# Unable to load application.properties file

Tags: java

What path should I be putting in here to load this `.properties` file?  I can't seem to get it to load...

```
InputStream stream = ProductVersionService.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.p‌​roperties");
properties.load(stream);
```

[image]

Comment: You are putting the right path, assuming that `resources`' contents are added to the classpath.

Comment: What do you have in your build path ?

Comment: Remove the slash char. Also, in my programs, I use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` but I'm not sure if it makes difference.

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: @cesarse No, that would make the application look for the `properties` file in the package containing `ProductVersionService`.

Comment: Is this assembled into a WAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see, you are using Maven to build this project and hence your final jar wont have src/main/resource or src/main/java either. All of these directories will be removed and all the contents beneath it will be added to root of jar and hence referring the path using src/main/* will result into an error. You should make use of

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to the properties file, from the root through the file itself: `/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: Correct! But path should be `/main/resources/application.properties`. Fix that and it will be a +1.

Comment: @brano88 moreover, the path may be different depending on the build phase. A complete answer would need to show how to validate that (ide/build process dependent).

Comment: `ProductVersionService.class.getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/application.p‌​roperties");` returns null

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/application.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `properties` files will be read from `war` package, easiest solution would be to load them as a `ResourceBundle`:

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("main.resources.application");
String prop = resourceBundle.getString("nameofproperty");
System.out.println(prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to develop something custom.

If you follow Spring architecture you can use this class:

```
org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils
```